# SSL Handshake failure for Android 2.2 version

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate

I am developing an application that need a certificate verification from the server. It works fine on Android 2.3 version and above, but for android 2.2 it gave me an exception :

```
W/System.err( 2116): java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err( 2116): error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1053 0x3a5208:0x00000003)
W/System.err( 2116):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeconnect(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2116):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:305)
W/System.err( 2116):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:502)
W/System.err( 2116):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:443)
```

This error came from BufferedInputStream when the device try to retrieve an InputStream from  SSLSocket. The code is below :

```
BufferedInputStream getSocketReader() throws IOException {
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream(), 32768);
        return bis;
    }
```

Here is my current code of createEasySSLContext() method:

```
private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(sampleKeystore, "password".toCharArray());

        CustomX509TrustManager trustManager = new CustomX509TrustManager(null);
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How is this happen? Can I fixed it without losing Android 2.2 support? Thank you.

Comment: EDIT : Now it doesn't work on 2.2 either. Now it gave me more headache :(

Comment: For me its throwing exception 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405902/adding-certificate-for-android-2-2

Comment: please help me too 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405902/adding-certificate-for-android-2-2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405902/adding-certificate-for-android-2-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely the CA that issued your server certificate is not trusted by Android 2.1. Either get a new certificate, or create a trust store that contains the CA certificate and setup your code to use it.

More info and some sample code [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html).

Comment: But my current code is ignoring server certificate verification. I do this only for testing. Is Android 2.1 checking the server certificate for the default?

Comment: Show your current code. If you are really ignoring the server cert, it might be some  SSL bug/incompatibility. There were some in 2.1. Enable server error logs, and check what exactly is causing the error to be sure.

Comment: I have edit my question above. As you can see, I don't give any KeyStore reference to CustomX509TrustManager() parameter. Also, inside CustomX509TrustManager class, I haven't implement any code for server certificate verification.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I missed the 'bad certificate' part. There are two likely possibilities: 1. either Android can't parse the certificate, or your server is requiring client authentication, and you are not sending a client cert from Android. To check on, try to parse to cert with OpenSSL, or just paste it somewhere so we can try :). For 2., check the server configuration (mod_ssl?).

Comment: Nikolay, thanks for your response. I have fixed the bad certificate part. Actually, it was because I use "PKCS12" Keystore type which is not supported by Android. Now, I am using "BKS", but it gave me a different exception. I updated the exception.

Comment: Looks like a client auth problem. What do the server logs say? Does the server trust the certificate you are sending?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunately, the server is not within my reach. I am an outsource programmer and they just give me access to their API. But the question is still remain, if my current code works fine on android 2.3 device, why it should fails on 2.2 and below?

Comment: Maybe you need to send the whole chain? Try adding the CA certificate to the key store.

Comment: You could try capturing the traffic with Wireshark and see what the actual SSL error is.

Comment: You mean I should add the server certificate as well? I will try it. The certificates they provide are self signed by the company that hire me.

Comment: Is there any Ubuntu version of Wireshark? I see only Windows and Mac on their download page. EDIT : I've found it, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I just realize that the provided certificate is unsigned. So this is my bad, I was focused on 2.3 case that somehow ignoring the unsecure certificate. Just need to wait for the new cert :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the cert from the server is not in a form that is recognized by 2.1. You might be able to fix this by changing the certificate or cipher algorithm that you use server end.